# Creating a WPF project from Reflector

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, .net-reflector

I'm new to using the .Net Reflector tool to decompile code. I have an application that I need to get the orginal source code for, this application was written using WPF technology. I've figured out so far that loading the yourprojectname.exe.deploy file gives most of the coding. Now the problem is converting it into a WPF project in Visual Studio. When I click 'Export Source Code' in .Net Reflector it exports the coding just fine, but not into a WPF project type. How can I achieve exporting the coding into a WPF project that will build?
I'm using .Net Reflector 8.5.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you are trying to change the project type: [How to change a Visual Studio project type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551586/how-to-change-a-visual-studio-project-type)

So you could change the Guid in the .csproj file into {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548} (WPF's Guid) from a text editor directly into the file.

But there may be other issues that you'll have to configure manually such as the output type "Class Library, Console Application and Windows Application" and the references (although reflector could have added the correct references already, I didn't test this)