# DotNetCore3.0 WPF - error - Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-3.0

I've created a WPF application using `VisualStudio 2017` by selecting the `.Net framework 4.6`. Know I'm trying to configure it for .Net Core 3.0 for WPF. But unfortunately, after changing my configuration, When reloading my projects, I got this error.

> Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing.

I've checked all the reference files are there.

Here is my `.csproj` file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>HelloWorld</AssemblyName>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="..\WpfApp\App.xaml" Link="App.xaml" />
    <Compile Include="..\WpfApp\App.xaml.cs" Link="App.xaml.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="..\WpfApp\MainWindow.xaml" Link="MainWindow.xaml" />
    <Compile Include="..\WpfApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs" Link="MainWindow.xaml.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've installed this SDK version `3.0.100-preview5-011568`. I've also enabled the Use previews of .Net Core SDK in VisualStudio.

Comment: *"after changing my configuration"* - what have you done exactly? Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025390/1997232) ? Rather follow [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551592/1997232).

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-net-core-3-create-wpf-application/

Comment: I've just changed the default configurations with the above one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should upgrade to Visual Studio 2019. It includes a project template for WPF and Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Core 3.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/wpf):

> Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support .NET Core 3.0 projects.